# Proof that $\det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det(A)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We can assume that A is $n{\times}n$ matrix. Prove that

$$\det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det(A)}$$

We know that $AA^{-1}=I$.

If someone could provide some insight on how to prove this that would be much appreciated

Thanks,

Tuki

Comment: Do you know that $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$?

Comment: product rule for determinants

Comment: I would assume this question comes in the course before you have the theorem that the product of determinants is the determinant of the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$AA^{-1}=I$$

$$det(AA^{-1})=det(I)$$

$$det(A)det(A^{-1})=1$$

If $det(A)\neq0$ then:

$$det(A^{-1})= \frac 1 {det(A)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the product rule for determinants : $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$, you have :

$$AA^{-1} = I \Leftrightarrow \det(AA^{-1}) = \det(I) \Leftrightarrow \det(A)\det(A^{-1}) = 1 \Leftrightarrow det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{det(A)} $$